# Solving equation using mathematica

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, mathematica-online, wave-equation, wave-propagation

How I can solve the equation :

$$R -\tan^{-1}[(m1/m3)*(k3/k1)] - \tan^{-1}[(m1/m2)*(k2/k1)]=0$$

I tried on it using findroot as following :

```
$$
F = 0.56; 
w0 = 4*10^9*3.14;
wp = 10*10^9*3.14;
gama = 0.03*wp;
T = 0.03*w0;
e1 = -3.7;
m1 = -1;
e2 = 1;
m2 = 1;
e3 = -9.5;
m3 = 1;
w = 4.6*10^9*3.14;
c = 3*10^8;
k0 = w/c;
k1 = Sqrt[(k0^2*e1*m1) - b^2];
k2 = Sqrt[b^2 - (k0^2*e2*m2)];
k3 = Sqrt[b^2 - (k0^2*e3*m3)];
R = 3.45;

bbValue = 
 FindRoot[R - ArcTan[(m1/m3)*(k3/k1)] - ArcTan[(m1/m2)*(k2/k1)] , {b,0.5}]$$
```

But it give me an error :

The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Regards

Comment: *How I can solve the equation* Solve it for what?

Comment: @Ghoster i want to solve it for b

Comment: There’s no $b$ in your equation. What is the point of writing the equation you are solving but not giving all the necessary info to check whether your code is correct?

Comment: it is not an error, just a warning on accuracy of root found. `b -> 2.34938*10^-13 - 3.75897 I}`

Comment: @Ghoster there are b in k1 , k2 and k3 ...

Comment: @Nasser is there another command we can use it to find  b ?!

Comment: You can simplify your equation a bit by using a formula for the sum of `ArcTan` and then applying `Tan`. You get then an algebraic equation.

Comment: @yarchik it give me the same error

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this plot

```
Plot[{Re[R - ArcTan[(m1/m3)*(k3/k1)] - ArcTan[(m1/m2)*(k2/k1)]], 
  Im[R - ArcTan[(m1/m3)*(k3/k1)] - ArcTan[(m1/m2)*(k2/k1)]]}, {b, -120, 120}]
```

Which root do you want to find?

[image]